# Is there a way to not to change type of varchar, when calculating time interval?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, varchar

The type of data in column "length" is varchar.
I need to calculate average length of audio.

Do I need to change data   type to datetime or is  there a way not to do this?

I am afraid, if I do it , my values may become incorrect.

Thanks!

Example

```
Length
22:32:00
11:22:12
10:00:00
```

Comment: Please provide the sample of length column value

Comment: @vinay chhabra. Updated

Comment: if it is varchar then it's not possible to get the average.. so in time of calculation you need to change it

Comment: you can use STR_TO_DATE(length,'%H:%i:%S') to change it to time at the time of calculation but i think this column is duration not time

Comment: @fa06.thanks. what is the better way to change type? I afraid that data becomes incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the data type to `time` because in its current format you cannot do any time calculations on your data without converting it to time anyway.

As mysql manual on the [time data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) says:

> TIME type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).

If you are worried about loosing some data due to incorrect formatting, then test varchar to time conversion using [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. Wherever it returns null with the proper mask used, your data is in the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your data format to a number -- but the number of seconds of duration.  You won't be limited to arbitrary limits on `time` and you can readily use the value for calculations.

If your `length` value is always 8 characters, you can do:

```
select (substring_index(length, ':', 1) * 60 * 60 +
        substr(length, 4, 2) * 60 +
        substring_index(length, ':', -1)
       ) as duration_seconds
```

If, after calculations, you want to represent the value as HH:MM:SS, you can convert back to that format.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. It is like can you multiply YourNAme and HisName?

So it should be converted to a real number.

However, you can still do some addtion or multiplication using mysql syntax alone. The engine will implicitly convert it for you.

From your example, every row has hh:mm:ss, right? where : is the column separation?
If not yet separated, use substring or [regex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) to separate it.

Assuming the hh, mm, and ss are separated.

You can actually perform arithmetic using SQL

```
SELECT 
    (SECONDS + MINUTES*60 + HOURS*60*60 ) as 'LengthInSeconds' 
FROM yourTable
```

If you didn't want to separate to columns, just use substring or regex to separate during query.

You can now just sum all the queries and divide it by Ntimes

After you get the value. You convert it back to hours, minutes, and seconds. See sample code below.

```
  //
  $average = $totalAccumulatedSeconds/3;

  // Time calculations for hours, minutes and seconds
  $hours = Math.floor(($average % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  $minutes = Math.floor(($average % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  $seconds = Math.floor(($average % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```

Actually you can perform several tests, if you really are afraid of calculations :)